# Безопасность сессий в PHP?

Tags: php, сессия, безопасность

В очередной раз работаю с **сессиями** в **PHP** и вдруг возникло ряд такий вопросов:

- А насколько они безопасны в данном
     языке,какова вероятность их
     подделать?
- Каковы средства защиты(в php),кроме привязки
     к ip и браузеру?
- Может кто-нибудь интересовался этим
     вопросом и у него есть готовые ответы
     или ссылки на статьи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как Вы знаете, сессии базируются на куках. Идентификатор сессии записывается в куки и по нему подымается сессия.

Никто не застрахован, что кто-то "подсмотрит" Ваш идентификатор и применит его в своих целях. Применяют дополнительные меры предосторожности, как Вы уже упомянули - привязка к IP и к User-Agent. Полной гарантии безопасности сессий не существует. На порядок безопасность повышает SSL (https) на сайте- это наверное единственная рекомендация, которую можно дать.

P.S.: А почему мой ответ отобразился как "Сообщество Хешкод" ? :)

Comment: А если ограничить область видимости идентификатора сессии,вызовет ли такой шаг,неудобство со стороны пользователей?

Comment: всмысле область видимости ? Вы про привязку к IP и UA ? Да, однозначно вызовет, во всяком случае IP и именно для тех, у кого динамический IP адресс.

Лучше выключить привязку к IP и включить SSL :)

Comment: Всмысле того,что значения сессии будут доступны только в тех местах где это необходимо.

Comment: И мне бы хотелось узнать,под каким ником скрывается счастливый обладатель ника "Cообщество ХэшКод"?Баг ли это или фича?

Comment: Сессии будут доступны на том домене, где их создадут, максимум можно сделать сессии доступными на поддоменах (чего хватает выше головы) 

>> И мне бы хотелось узнать,под каким ником скрывается счастливый обладатель ника "Cообщество ХэшКод"?Баг ли это или фича?

это я. Боюсь что это таки баг.

Comment: @shurik Ответ отобразился как "Сообщество ...", потому что при отправке была выставлена галочка общий (видимо случайно).

Answer (score 3):

1. сессии привязываются к конкретному браузеру, создается уникальный id и записывается в переменную PHPSESSID. обратно она возвращается двумя путями через cookies и GET либо POST запросом. в связи с этим сессию подделать можно.
2. можно дополнительно пользоваться одноразовыми токенами, которые усложнят доступ к сессии.
3. здесь достаточно подробно расписано о принципе действия сессий. [Сессии в PHP](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=070)

Comment: Одноразовыми токенами..даже не представляю как это выглядит в сочетании с php.

Comment: @diRect_Z я так понимаю слово токен ввело вас в заблуждение. в данном случае под токеном я имел ввиду одноразовый уникальный ключ который присваивается каждому событию требующему доступа к сессии, либо к действиям требующих особой защиты.

Comment: Меня ввело в заблуждение способ реализации всего этого на php.

Comment: особо сложного ничего нет, генерируем ключ, записываем его в базу вместе с датой и id пользователя, когда ключ вернулся удаляем, если время действия ключа истекло, тоже удаляем.

Comment: То есть создаем отдельную таблицу,привязиваем ее к id пользователя и т.д.Ясно.Большое спасибо.

Comment: @FLK Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, а как вернется ключ? То есть это случится при краже кук? Не особо понял способ реализации, а хочется именно его реализовать:)

Answer (score 2):

Если украсть куки и подставить (если нет других мер защиты, типа привязки по IP), то сессия будет украдена.