# Особенности $_SESSION php

Tags: php, сессия

Насколько безопасным является использование сессий в php?

Безопасно ли делать авторизацию пользователей через сессии на php? Является ли кука `phpsessionid` httpOnly? Какое время жизни сессии в php по умолчанию?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/session.security.php

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/95360/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536670/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465186/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472954/186083 если поиск не работает.

Answer (score 1):

1. Насколько безопасным является использование сессий в php? Безопасно ли делать авторизацию пользователей через сессии на php?

   **Ответ:** Да, безопасно (см. http://php.net/manual/ru/session.security.php)

   > "Работа с HTTP сессиями является основой web безопасности."

---

2. Является ли кука phpsessionid httpOnly?

   **Ответ:** По умолчанию - нет. 
   Вы можете изменить это, задав свойство: `session.cookie_httponly`.

   Пример:
   `ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1)`

---

3. Какое время жизни сессии в php по умолчанию?

   **Ответ:** (см. http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

   > По умолчанию кука будет валидна до закрытия браузера